# nginx (13: Permission denied) on socket

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, permissions, django, uwsgi

I'm trying to set up a Django app using uwsgi and nginx, but I keep butting my head against a very irritating problem.
I've used the [uwsgi docs](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) as a reference guide.

When serving the app through uwsgi (`uwsgi --http :8000 --module myproject.wsgi`) everything works fine, but when I try to connect through a socket with nginx (`uwsgi --ini myproject.ini`) and open `myproject.com:8000/<django-app>` in my browser I get a 502 error and

> 2018/02/07 08:25:26 [crit] 30339#30339: *1 connect() to unix:///var/www/[myproject]/[myproject].sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: [client-ip], server: [server-ip], request: "GET /[django-app]/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "unix:///var/www/[myproject]/[myproject].sock:", host: "[fqdn]:8000"

this ^ in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

My project folder is under `/var/www/`, owned by `<me>:www-data`, and with `764` as permissions. Every subfolder and file is (currently) under this ownership and these permissions.

I'm running everything on a Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine (managed by my admin), and my user has `sudo` access.

---

Am I missing something obvious?

---

**Update:**
For the moment, everything is working when `other` has `read-write` permissions on the socket, and `read-execute` permissions on the rest of the project.
So nginx is not recognized as it should... I've double-checked, and nginx is running as the `www-data` user, which is the group-owner of my entire project, and which has `read-execute` permissions, just as `other` now has.

---

`myproject_nginx.conf`
(In addition to the settings in this file, I've put `user www-data www-data;` in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.)

```
# myproject_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:///var/www/myproject/myproject.sock;
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name my.ip.goes.here; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /var/www/myproject/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/myproject/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /var/www/myproject/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

---

`myproject_uwsgi.ini`

```
# myproject_uwsgi.ini file
[uwsgi]

# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir          = /var/www/myproject
# Django's wsgi file
module         = myproject.wsgi
# the virtualenv (full path)
home           = /var/www/myenv

# process-related settings
master         = true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes      = 10
# the socket (full path)
socket         = /var/www/myproject/myproject.sock
# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
chmod-socket   = 666
uid            = me
gid            = www-data
# clear environment on exit
vacuum         = true
```

Answer (score 2):

After a few hours of pain I found a solution to this exact issue.

The problems are two:
1) the folder's permissions
2) the virtual environment

The virtual environment messes with your permissions and prevents uwsgi from creating the socket correctly - just deactivate the venv and pip install django and uwsgi system wide. There may be a way to solve this within the venv, but I don't know of any.

Then, set your django project folder's permissions to 777 (or change its owner to root).

cd into the folder and run the wsgi command as root:

```
sudo uwsgi --socket mysite.sock --module mysite.wsgi --chmod-socket=664 --uid www-data --gid www-data
```

this creates mysite.sock with owner www-data and I no longer get the permission denied error.

I hope this helps.

-edit-
after some more investigation, I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-debian-8) tutorial and got it working as a systemd service without any of these issues - I guess the official tutorial takes some things for granted.

Answer (score 0):

I hit a similar problem based on a similar digital ocean tutorial.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04#

My hack was to `chmod a+rw mysite.sock` after starting uwsgi.

However, I imagine changing --chmod-socket=666 would also work.

Comment: The socket file is created and destroyed each time you run uwsgi so changing perms manually is not a sustainable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I always start out when doing deployment development and/or testing by running something like this:

```
uwsgi --socket /tmp/mysite.sock --module mysite.wsgi --chmod-socket=777
```

Then once you see your site working, you can work towards using the INI file method. This is nice because the command to start your app server is simplified to:

```
uwsgi --ini mysite.ini
```

Giorgio Ghisotti already mentioned all this so that answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

In this tutorial for [Using Unix sockets instead of ports](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html), this command worked:

```
uwsgi --socket mysite_nginx.sock --wsgi-file test.py --chmod-socket=666
```